# Port 80 showing as filtered, but ufw allowing port 80

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I am having trouble with apache on my Ubuntu server. It is not a local machine, I am accessing it through SSH. When I run `nmap -sS 127.0.0.1` it shows this:

```
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp open     ssh
80/tcp filtered HTTP
```

ports.conf is setup listening to port 80 like so:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Its worth mentioning I also tried setting it to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`

I cant seem to get port 80 to open as opposed to being set to filtered. When I run `sudo ufw status verbose` its saying:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

    To                         Action      From
    --                         ------      ----
    80,443/tcp                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere
    22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
    80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
    22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

So I don't think its a firewall issue. Running `ss -tunapl` shows the following:

```
Netid   State     Recv-Q    Send-Q              Local Address:Port       Peer Address:Port
udp     UNCONN    0         0             172.31.255.175%eth0:68              0.0.0.0:*       users:(("systemd-network",pid=19297,fd=17))
tcp     LISTEN    0         128                       0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*       users:(("sshd",pid=17786,fd=3))
tcp     LISTEN    0         128                          [::]:22                 [::]:*       users:(("sshd",pid=17786,fd=4))
tcp     LISTEN    0         128                             *:80                    *:*       users:(("apache2",pid=27990,fd=4),("apache2",p                                   id=27989,fd=4),("apache2",pid=27987,fd=4))
```

Also, running `iptables --table filter --list --numeric` shows outputs [this (pastebin link).](https://pastebin.com/FF0QU7ww)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your pastebin iptables rules listing link:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
...
```

So, the first rule in the INPUT chain is port 80 DROP rule. However, your listing is missing critical network interface information, which can be obtained using this command instead: `sudo iptables -xvnL`.

EDIT: The new pastebin shows no network interface dependence and also shows packets taking the first DROP rule path, as expected:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     434    23648 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
```

So, you need to delete that rule (untested):

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT 1
```

It is not obvious as to why that rule is/was there in the first place.

Comment: I dont really understand what im looking at in here, maybe [this will help.](https://pastebin.com/fjgTzPTy) Its another pastebin of the sudo iptables -xvnL command

Comment: Deleting that rule worked, thanks so much!